# Dynamic disk size a VM using libvirt

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Heyy i could not figure out if dynamic disk size(hard disk size according to contents which expands and contracts dynamically) is supported in libvirt or not. If yes what are the appropriate parameters to be passed on in virt-install.

Thanks in advance,
Jatin kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try command `virsh domblkinfo <domain> <path-to-block-device>`

For example, you have a windows guest that uses a 10GB file /data/winxp.img as disk device:

```
# virsh domblkinfo windows-guest /data/winxp.img
Capacity: 10737418240
Allocation: 3041759232
Physical: 3041759232
```

You can try command `qemu-img` if you want to do this job to your disk file without libvirt running:

```
# qemu-img info /data/winxp.img
```

Refer to [this API doc](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainGetBlockInfo) for detail info